# ApexREST Websrvice StatusCode with ResponseBody

Tags: rest-api, api, webservices, rest, apexrest

I am writing a REST Webservice and have the following piece of Code.

```
 @RestResource(urlMapping='/UpdateTransaction')
  global with sharing class OpportunityTransaction {
  @HttpPost
 global static void updateOpportunity() { 

    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response; 
    Blob body = req.requestBody;
    String requestString = body.toString();
    if(body == null || requestString.contains('{}')){
        res.statusCode = 204; 
        res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(res.statusCode+' : "No Content" success code for Message request; resend the request as part of the message loop.');
        System.debug('response Body:::'+String.valueOf(res.responseBody));
     }
```

My problem is that, I am not being able to receive the custom message in the other application(which calls the web service) for statusCode 204. It just shows the standard message 204 No Content. The responsebody is displayed correctly in the debug log. Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 204 response cannot include a message body:

> A 204 response is terminated by the first empty line after the header
> fields because it cannot contain a message body.

> -- [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5)

In fact, a 204 might not be appropriate here, since you're trying to convey a message that is arguably not a "success" message; you're asking the client to do something different. This would normally be a 4xx-class error message instead.

*No Content* does not mean that the **client** sent no data. Instead, it means that the request was successful and there was no content to return to the client from the server.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you very much for the explanation.